# Validate HTML form checkbox with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am trying to validate a checkbox in a HTML form through a javascript function. I have been able to get the form to return false if left unchecked, but I cannot get the form to submit when the box is checked. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.randyconnolly.com/tests/process.php" id="mainForm" onsubmit="return Validate()">

<div id="rectangle"> 
           <label>I accept the software license</label>
           <input id="accept" type="checkbox" name="accept" class="required">
        </div>

function Validate() {
//Form Validate
var t = document.getElementById("title").value;
if (t == "") {
    alert("Empty Title Field");
    document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}else{
    document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

var d = document.getElementById("description").value;
if (d == "") {
    alert("Empty description field");
    document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}else{
    document.getElementById("description").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

var c = document.getElementById("accept");
if (c.checked != "true") {
    alert("Please accept license");
    document.getElementById("rectangle").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById("accept").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

}

Comment: could you post the corresponding HTML?

Comment: do you actually see the "Please accept license" when not checked? I believe c.checked returns a boolean so u also dont need to check against string - that might actually be the problem?

Comment: Yes, it does flag the alert for the checkbox. But it will trigger it every time whether the box is checked or not.                                                                    Edit: I have also tried if(c!="true"), it performs the same.

Comment: Could you show us your entire form? How are you submitting it?

Comment: Are you returning a "true" value if everything is valid?  Also, do you need to use a "GET" method for your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you change your checked logic slightly.  You'll want to compare against boolean true instead of string "true"

```
if (c.checked != true) {
    alert("Please accept license");
    document.getElementById("rectangle").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    return false;
}else{
    document.getElementById("rectangle").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

edit: I changed the element id passed in the else block so that it would correctly set #rectangle background to white.